# Lightweight browser for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, web-browser

I'd like to find a lightweight, fast browser for Windows 7.  I would like it to create ONE task, not a gajillion tasks when there are multiple tabs open (see note at bottom of question).  Adblocking is important to me because I have trouble reading with distracting images on the page, especially when they appear with a time lag and the text starts shifting around.

What I have tried so far:

Firefox: Memory usage spikes and I have to restart frequently.

Chrome and Opera: Each tab generates multiple processes, slowing down the computer.

Midori: Font was awful.  Could not customize very much.  (Example: could not control where the bookmarks were displayed.)  Could not find understandable support for Midori for Windows.

I don't mind purchasing or paying a subscription fee if that would help.

**Important**: I'm happy to provide additional information to the problem description if needed.

*(Note: why do I have so many tabs open?  Because if I execute a web search about an issue, I find it efficient to do control-enter for each likely-looking hit, and then start skimming the results but moving from tab to tab.)*

Comment: You can disable the "multiprocess" design flaw in all Chromium-based browsers with a command line switch: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models. Sometimes however some browsers become buggy on it (as the link shows), so a browser without the flaw is always preferable.

Comment: @Alejandro - The link says: "any renderer crash will cause the loss of the entire browser process."  I can live with that if it's only once an hour.  So I could do that with Opera or Portable Firefox or Google, if I understood that right.  I guess I'd prefer Portable Firefox (so I can use the add-ons I've gotten to know well).  Does this sound reasonable?  How do I do the command line switch?  Shall I write a question so you can file an answer, at a different SE site?

Comment: That's true, but in typical usage it seems to be nowhere near an hour, but rather a very rare occurrence. That applies to any Chrome clone, so Firefox is out of the question (and it's neither flawed in the way Chrome is). Just edit the shortcut and add the parameter at the end. Otherwise, [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) seems the most appropriate to me.

Comment: @Alejandro - Okay, thanks, so I could use that tip with Opera or Chrome, I guess?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [**QupZilla**](https://www.qupzilla.com/about).

> QupZilla is a new and very fast QtWebEngine browser. It aims to be a lightweight web browser available through all major platforms.

And:

> ...Above that, it has by default enabled blocking ads with a built-in AdBlock plugin.

Windows download is here: https://www.qupzilla.com/download#windows

Comment: Looks like QupZilla changed its name to [Falkon](https://www.falkon.org/about/)?